# how to make a expandable block on android

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

I have ListFragment with product list. first item short description product with button "full description", when user click on this button revealed a complete description. and when user finished read description, he scroll down to the product. how make this ? maybe use ExpandableList ?

Comment: add [expandable listview](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)

Comment: how put expandableListView in LiastFragment ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. simple use

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View head = inflater.inflate(R.layout....,null);
            getListView().addHeaderView(head);
```

and use animation

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement expandable listview...here is a great tutorial with source code you can use http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: when I make expandable listView and join to ListFragment like: `getListView().addHeaderView(head);`  I see only name group, without children

Comment: Why are you using list fragment...you can use Fragment with expandable listview in it

Comment: I use TabHost , in another tab i use another lists